# Explain behavior of default priority_queue::top()?

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

The `std::priority_queue`, by default uses a `std::vector<int>` and the `std::less` comparator.  By default, priority_queue is a max heap.

The [docs for top()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/top/) states:

> The *top element* is the element that compares higher in the `priority_queue`, and the next that is removed from the container when `priority_queue::top` is called.
>
> This member function effectively calls member `front` of the underlying container object.

Therefore a default constructed `priority_queue` of integers constructed like so:

```
auto maxheap = priority_queue<int>();
maxHeap.push(1);
maxHeap.push(3);
cout << maxHeap.top(); // outputs 3
```

However, going back to the description of `top()`, the docs state that, effectively, the member `front` on the underlying container object is called.  If I create a vector and sort using `std::less` to mimic the underlying container of our maxHeap:

```
auto vec = vector<int>{3, 1};
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), less<int>()); // {1, 3}
cout << vec.front(); // outputs 1
```

Because `std::less` sorts in ascending order, calling `vec.front()` ends up returning the smallest value.

There's some disconnect in my understanding of how the default behavior of `priority_queue::top()` and what the docs say.  Can some explain this to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong algorithm, you can read at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue
that `std::priority_queue` doesn't use `std::sort`, but `std::make_heap`.

If you use it in your example as well, you get the output you're expecting.

```cpp
std::vector<int> queue{1, 3};
std::make_heap(queue.begin(), queue.end(), std::less<>{});
std::cout << queue.front() << '\n';

Output: 3
```